# How to do conditional formatting in MS word

Tags: ms-word, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do conditional formatting in ms word exactly similar to excel in the form of traffic light, where 1 is red, 2 is yellow and 3 is green. However, I am struggling to implement this logic in ms word. Please help!

Thanks,
PS

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254 and, if this is for a mailmerge, *Conditionally Format Mailmerge Output* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Follow  macropod's advice. Conditional formatting in Word is different on a structural level from that in Excel. In Excel, the commands evaluate something and change the formatting of the subject cell(s) based on that evaluation. In Word there are complete copies of everything in the different formats and the evaluation decides which to display.